# Rails: form.error_messages does not wrap custom validated fields in a fieldWithErrors div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model that uses the low level `validate_on_create` method, based on a simple condition I'm adding an error message to the field, e.g

```
self.errors.add(:expiry_date, "is too soon") if self.expiry_date && self.expiry_date < Date.today + 1.week
```

When rendering the view 'new' after a failed save the field isn't picked up by `error_messages_for` as I would expect. The error is shown in the ususal list of errors that indicated the validation is working correctly.

Has anybody got any idea why this is? I guess `form.error_messages` isn't looking at all errors on the object?

Added the requested code:

```
<% form_for([:solicitor, @policy]) do |form| %>
  <%= form.error_messages :message => "See the list of reasons below to find out why not:", :header_message => "Sorry but we cannot yet create your policy  based on the information you've provided." %>
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:form => form} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Let's see your form_for and form.error_messages view code.

Comment: I've just added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a simple typo in the form partial. I should have posted **all** the code in question as I'm sure if I did  BJ Clark or others would have easily spotted the silly mistake I made

Lesson learned!

Answer (score 4):

More than likely your problem is:

1. You are not passing the form_for the correct options.
2. You are redirecting back to the form instead of rendering.
3. You aren't using the form_for builders (ie text_field_tag instead of f.text_field)

However, without posting your full controller/view, I'm basically just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and sorry I don't post up enough for you to really see the problem.